# Anyone know much about the Rainbird sprinkler nozzles, HEVAN, VAN, Q, etc?

Tags: plumbing, water, generator, sprinkler-system, irrigation

Got a setup with sprinklers spaced every 8'. We installed a generator and I need to move sprinklers around to get coverage and prevent sprinklers from spraying the generator. I moved the sprinkler over 4' next to the generator. I was going to put a 90° nozzle on it to prevent spraying on the generator. Problem is, I am going to lose water coverage because the space between the sprinklers is now 12'.

I wanted to ask you guys but I believe I need to add a middle sprinkler with a 6 VAN 180° nozzle in the middle to cover the middle space and a 6 VAN 90° on the side to avoid spraying the generator.

The house to the fence is 6'4".

Couple questions:

1. How should I correct this? Should I put a sprinkler at 6' between the two sprinklers?
2. What nozzle should I use for the middle sprinkler and for sprinkler #2? 6VAN?
3. If I need to add a middle sprinkler, can I use a T coupler? Would [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L462x.jpg) be the proper way to connect a middle sprinkler to the water supply? This isn't a long run and the water pressure is pretty strong.

The original nozzle that was there was a 15Q.
[image: original nozzle]

It's been raining nonstop and wasn't able to finish
[image: started raining and wasn't able to finish]

Diagram for adding a middle sprinkler
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprinkler #2 should be a low angle 90 Deg. 6ft. The sprinkler you add should be a low angle 180 deg. 6ft. You don't tell us what is beyond Sprinkler #1 to the left on your diagram. Assuming a continuation of your yard, I would go with another low angle 180. This gives you the recommended 200% coverage.
Here in Fla. sprinklers are plentiful. Buying the VAN units is more expensive than just getting a fixed 90 and 180 spray nozzle.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it is a continuation of the yard with 15Qs along the side of the house. I dont know why the installer used Qs for a straight run or why they are 15s.

Comment: Which type of nozzle you recommend? I can get a fixed like the 8Q and 8H but I dont think they come as 6Q and 6H. Also, I am not familiar with a "low angle" what you mean by that? Physically moving the sprinkler head at an angle?  **I picked VAN because that is the only 6 foot I could find that I could adjust down. If you have a part number for a different nozzle you recommend, I can look it up.

Comment: "Low angle" means the spray is distributed closer to the ground.  The 8h and 8Q can be adjusted down to as low as 3ft. spacing.

Comment: Thanks RMD, I got an 8H and 8Q and turned down the pressure. Getting perfect coverage.